# sql query problem

Tags: sql

```
id  categories  ext_categories
2      36      17,250
8      20      28
10     17      18
```

if query `categories = 17` I can get results like this

```
id
2  (ext_categories field)
10
```

How to query `ext_categories` for `id: 2`

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to simply get ext_category for id=2 then try "select ext_categories from table where id=2"

Comment: Don't put multiple values into a single column! This violates the first normal form of database design - and it's a big no-no. It also creates all sorts of messy code when trying to deal with that kind of data.... just **don't** do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the field `ext_categories` implemented?  For example, are you using a varchar field and pipe-delimited string (of numbers) as values with the strict format

```
|n|...
```

so that your table looks like

```
id  categories  ext_categories
2      36      "|17|250|"
8      20      "|28|"
10     17      "|18|"
```

instead?

If so, try

```
select * from table where categories = 17 OR ext_categories like '%|250|%'
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for group by?

```
select id,ext_categories From YOURTABLENAME group by id,ext_categories
```

Comment: i guess i got lost with your newly updates on your question, my answer isnt valid now,, please explain more

Answer (score 0):

You want to include `ext_categories` in the results? Or you want a field from a foreign table based on the ID of `ext_categories` ?

If the later;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE categories = 17 OR ext_categories =17 LEFT JOIN ext_category_table on ext_category_table.ext_category = ext_categories"
```